# How to allow Ada Big_Numbers in GPS Community 2021

Tags: ada, gnat-gps

With Ada 2022, `Ada.Numerics.Big_Numbers` can be enabled by setting `-gnatwi` somewhere according to the error I get in GPS Community Edition 2021.

`warning: "Ada.Numerics.Big_Numbers" is an Ada 2022 unit [-gnatwi]`

I assume the flag must be set for the compiler so I modified the `Compiler` package in my gpr-file like so:

```
  package Compiler is
      for Default_Switches ("Ada") use
        Compile_Checks_Switches &
        Build_Switches &
        Runtime_Checks_Switches &
        Style_Checks_Switches &
        Contracts_Switches &
        ("-gnatw.X", -- Disable warnings for No_Exception_Propagation
         "-gnatQ", -- Don't quit. Generate ALI and tree files even if illegalities
         "-gnatwi"); -- Big_Numbers
   end Compiler;
```

Note the `-gnatwi` flag at the end.

But GPS still complains wenn I try "Build->Check Semantic" on a file where `with Ada.Numerics.Big_Numers` is set.
Restarting GPS also did not help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

options starting with `-gnatw` is just about warnings:

```
-gnatwxx  Enable selected warning modes, xx = list of parameters:
    i*+  turn on warnings for implementation unit
```

You probably want:

```
   -gnatX    Language extensions permitted
```

Edit:

As Simon Wright pointed out in the comments, `-gnat2020` should work, and is a better option, even though it doesn't seem to be documented.

Comment: yes! thanks that solved it

Comment: So far as I know, `-gnatX` allows experimental features that may not ever get into the language; `-gnat2020` is perhaps safer

Comment: @SimonWright Yeah, you're right, except it doesn't seem to be documented

Comment: Probably because it will be changed in the future. When the new standard arrives, perhaps it will be an invalid switch.